# What is the expected distance from the mean of a multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

For a multivariate Gaussian distribution $p(x) = N(x\mid \mu,\Sigma)$, what is $E[\|x-\mu\|]$?

I know from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115508/how-to-calculate-variance-of-gaussian-given-mean-and-average-deviation) that $E[|x-\mu|]=\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$ for univariate Gaussians.

But I couldn't find a definition of standard deviation for multivariate Gaussians. Could it be something like $\|\sqrt{\boldsymbol\lambda}\|\sqrt{2/\pi}$, where $\boldsymbol\lambda$ is the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$?

Comment: You have $$\Sigma = \operatorname{E}( (x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.$$ That's the analog in $n$ dimensions of the variance of $x$.  Feller calls it the variance; some others call it the covariance since the entries in this matrix are the covariances between univariate components. I sort of analog of the standard deviation is the symmetric positive-definite square root of $\Sigma$, which in the same basis that diagonalizes $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. $\qquad$

Comment: I am also very interested in this, could you summarize this to an answer? OP is asking for a single value, you describe a matrix, correct?